# How to get full Ubuntu installed on Nexus 7 2013?

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

Is it possible to get a full Ubuntu system up and running on a Nexus 7 2013?

I'm aware of the [Ubuntu Phone project](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone) and also the [Ubuntu Nexus 7 project](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation) but Phone isn't full Ubuntu and the Nexus 7 project is unsupported and I can't get it to boot on the 2013 Nexus 7. Are there any other community efforts that can successfully install and boot full Ubuntu on a 2013 Nexus 7?

**Update**
I’ve successfully installed Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 7 with

```
ubuntu-device-flash --channel=devel --bootstrap
```

but this is the Touch version and I'm looking to get full Ubuntu installed. I've tried `ubuntu-device-flash --channel=ubuntu-core/devel --bootstrap` but I get an error:

```
$ ubuntu-device-flash --channel=ubuntu-core/devel --bootstrap
2015/02/13 21:09:10 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2015/02/13 21:09:10 Device is |flo|
2015/02/13 21:09:10 Device flo not found on server https://system-image.ubuntu.com channel ubuntu-core/devel
```

Is there a channel with full (desktop) Ubuntu that will install on the Nexus 7, and if so, what command is used to install it?

Comment: Hey, i'm trying the same thing on my nexus 7. In the last command, "ubuntu-device-flash --channel=devel --bootstrap", i get: "unknown flag: channel". What's up??